# This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key connectionView: JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: objective-c, jsqmessagesviewcontroller, nsunknownkeyexception

I'm attempting to call/load an instance of JSQMessagesViewController I'm reusing from a previous/different project and I'm getting the following error message:

```
 "This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key connectionView."
```

I believe the issue is being caused by an issue in the following (a part of my `WidgetsVC.m` file):

```
  case 2:{

        JSQChat *fcvc = [[JSQChat alloc] initWithNibName:@"JSQChat" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [appDelegate.chatNavController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:fcvc]
                                                   animated:NO];
        appDelegate.cpTabBarController .selectedIndex = 2;


        break;
```

I've tried many of the suggestions commonly associated with this error and none of them seem to resolve it (uninstalling the app, bad connection in XIB, checking to ensure Targets > Summary > iPhone/iPod Deployment Info > Main Interface is blank, etc. etc.):

[What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: … this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key-v)

Comment: The second answer in the other question you linked is probably what you need to look into.

Comment: I've looked at the 'Outlets' for JSQChat.xib and I don't have a little ! or anything else indicating something is broken as mentioned in the second answer... (any other ideas/suggestions are appreciated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create a `JSQChat` object from the JSQChat.xib file.  The xib specifies that the object you create will have a `connectionView` outlet.  `JSQChat` doesn't have such an outlet defined.

Probably the reason that you don't see anything broken in the visual editor is that you've defined the xib's file owner to be `HomeVC`, with does contain:

```
    IBOutlet UIView *connectionView;
```